# Match a specific regex using matches()

Tags: regex, xpath, xpath-3.0

Trying to match a specific word using matches()

```
*//id[matches(.,lower-case('*\s?Xander\s?*'))]
```

Examples:

```
Set of Xanderous- No match
Xander Tray of 6- Match
Tray of 6 pieces Xander- Match
Set of 6 Xander pieces- Match
```

Any instance of the exact word 'Xander' match is the objective.

Comment: Would using word boundaries match the case if the exact word is available anywhere in the tag

Comment: How do you define an exact word?

Comment: For example in this case, match only 'Xander' if it is present in the text tag..and not matches words like 'Xanderous'

Comment: Only between letters? Letters and digits? Letters, digits, and underscores?

Comment: Letters,digits,quotes (both single and double)

Comment: I understand the quotes are not considered a word part. Try `matches(lower-case(.),'(.*[^a-z0-9])?xander([^a-z0-9].*)?')`, or if the pattern is not anchored bt default, `matches(lower-case(.), '^(.*[^a-z0-9])?xander([^a-z0-9].*)?$')` (do not use `lower-case` on the pattern!)

Comment: Can you explain if possible what this part (.*[^a-z0-9])? is for..thanks

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: No..it matches 'xander' even if it is in between letters like 'alexander'

Comment: It is impossible, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rYC3OD/1). I modified the regex a bit since it is a demo against a single multiline text block.

Comment: the pattern is anchored..on using matches(lower-case(.),'(.*[^a-z0-9])?xander([^a-z0-9].*)?') getting no match if the title contains words like 'xanderous'..however getting a match if the title contains words like say 'alexander' where xander is a subset

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `'(.*[^a-z0-9])?xander([^a-z0-9].*)?'` matches only the exact term when used as a standalone regex..however when used inside `matches()`, it matches even when it is a part of a bigger wrd...any idea why..thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help more, I do not have a testing environment.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the XPath regex dialect doesn't handle word boundaries is that to do it properly, you need to be language-sensitive - a "word" is a cultural artefact.

You could do `tokenize(., '\P{L}+') = 'Xander'` which tokenizes treating any sequence of non-letters as a separator and then tests if one of the tokens is 'Xander'.

Comment: I think that's very clever to use `tokenize`. To make this case-insensitive it would be `*//id[tokenize(lower-case(.), '\P{L}+') = 'xander']`, right?

Comment: Yes (or use a case-blind collation for the comparison). But the question asked for an exact match on "Xander", not a case-blind match.

Comment: The case-insensitive reasoning I made is based on OP's own attempt to include `lower-case`.

Comment: Yes, I found that puzzling too, but I try to resist the temptation to infer requirements from non-working code.

Answer (score 1):

I have been running some tests and it seems word boundaries are not integrated into the XML/XPATH vocabulary. So the next best thing IMO is to test for a whitespace **or** start/end string anchors surrounding zero or more characters. Therefore, I ended up with:

```
*//id[matches(lower-case(.),'.*(^|\s)xander($|\s).*')]
```

Even better would be to drop `lower-case` alltogether and use the third `matches` parameter (flags) setting it to case-insensitive matching:

```
*//id[matches(.,'.*(^|\s)xander($|\s).*','i')]
```

Comment: matches(lower-case(.),'.*(^|\s)xander($|\s).*')->..this helps..thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Roughly, if you want to get the full line matching if it exactly contains the word `Xander`, you can use `\b` which delimits a specific word, plus some **greedy** operators `.*`:

```
^.*\bXander\b.*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/PvKptN/1

Or if you don't need the whole line, you can simply check if it contains `Xander`:

```
\bXander\b
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/PvKptN/2

I hope it satisfies the regex flavor you're using

Comment: Can ^.*\bXander\b.*$  be used inside matches..like matches(text(),('^.*\bXander\b.*$'))

Comment: \b isn't available in XPath